# Unable to present a Controller on Formsheet style Controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am working on Custom presentation style and having one issue. what i have using is https://github.com/ergunemr/BottomPopup library but unable to present in visible context!!

[image]

i already change the code in below method at `BottomPopupPresentAnimator` class

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)! // sub
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!  // plan
        transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
        let presentFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: fromVC)
        let initialFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: fromVC.view.frame.height), size: presentFrame.size)
        toVC.view.frame = initialFrame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            toVC.view.frame = presentFrame
        }) { (_) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }
```

what i achieve is

[image]

i already tried with different type of combination with presentation style

can anyone suggest what is wrong here? i just want to present over middle controller **(Popup Setting)**